# Multiple form submit with only one jQuery Ajax

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

I have a page where is 3-4 form in divs, and I want to submit it with only one script and I want to refresh the actual div content (where is the form). But I don't know how to specify the actual div or form for the ajax post.

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $(".ajaxform").submit(function() {
        var id = $(this).attr('id');
        var dataString = $(this).serialize();
        $.ajax({
             url:'../tools/tools.php',
             data: dataString + '&form=' + id,
             type: 'POST', 
             success: function(html)
            {
            $('#actualdiv').load(document.URL +  ' #actualdiv');
            } 
        });       
    });
});
```

The forms or divs have unique id for the tools.php where I can run the actual form's mysql.

Comment: Why not: `$('#actualdiv').html(html);` ? This would replace the content with the response.

Comment: Because with that, I should put the html of the form to the tools again, and I  just want to reload it because of the changed data of the inputs.

Comment: Expand on what you mean by 'reload it', the entire page?

Comment: No, only the div which contains a form, where is a mysqli query. It's an update form so it loads the actual data from mysql. And there 2-3 of it on the page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are posting data and then receiving new forms back as a response, I would make the function more dynamic.

```
function loadNextForm(form, id){
   var dataString = form.serialize();
   $.ajax({
     url:'../tools/tools.php',
     data: dataString + '&form=' + id,
     type: 'POST', 
     success: function(newForm) {
       $('#actualdiv').html(newForm);
     } 
   });
}

$(document).ready(function(){
  $(".ajaxform").on("submit", function(){
    loadNextForm($(this), $(this).attr('id'));
  });
});
```

This should allow you to POST the data, get the new form, place it into the DIV, and allow it to be a functional form that can process the next form.